# Bootstrap video carousel wont autopay

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a bootstrap video carousel but it won't autoplay the videos when the page loads or when the items on the carousel change. Any ideas on how to do this? I need the first video to play onload and every video after that to play when the carousel changes items. I don't care if we use JQuery or just HTML or whatever I just need it to work.

```
<?php include('header.php');?>

<!-- Carousel =========================== -->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!-- first slide -->
        <div class="item active">
            <video autoplay="true" loop="true" class="first-slide">
                <source src="StockTemplates/4thofJuly/4thofJuly_HD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Welcome to Creative Engine</h1>
                    <p>text about ce</p>
                </div><!-- end .carousel-caption -->
            </div><!-- end .container -->
        </div><!-- end .item active -->
        <!--End first slide-->

        <!-- second slide -->
        <div class="item">
            <video class="second-slide" loop="true" autoplay="true">
                <source src="StockTemplates/25PercentOff/25PercentOff_HD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Slide 2 Heading</h1>
                    <p>slide 2 text</p>
                </div><!-- end .carousel-caption -->
            </div><!-- end .container -->
        </div><!-- end .item active -->
        <!--end second slide-->

        <!-- third slide -->
        <div class="item">
            <video class="third-slide" loop="true" autoplay="true">
                <source src="StockTemplates/Abstract105/Abstract105_HD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Slide 3 Heading</h1>
                    <p>Slide 3 Text</p>
                </div><!-- end .carousel-caption -->
            </div><!-- end .container -->
        </div><!-- end .item active -->
        <!--end third slide-->

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glipicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a><!-- end .left carousel-control -->
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glipicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a><!-- end .right carousel-control -->

    </div><!-- end .carousel-inner -->
</div><!-- end #myCarousel -->
<div class="descriptionSection">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="mainDescriptionHeading">Creating the perfect ad has never been easier</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="test.jpg" class="icon img-circle center-block">
                <h4 class="descriptionHeading">Setup a display</h4>
                <p class="descriptionParagraph">Tell us the resolution of your display and what file types it supports.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="test.jpg" class="icon img-circle center-block">
                <h4 class="descriptionHeading">Choose a template</h4>
                Search though our growing libary of templates and choose the perfect theme for your ad!
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="test.jpg" class="icon img-circle center-block">
                <h4 class="descriptionHeading">Customize</h4>
                <p class="descriptionParagraph">type in a custom message, choose your colors, and upload your company logo</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="test.jpg" class="icon img-circle center-block">
                <h4 class="descriptionHeading">Get the video</h4>
                <p class="descriptionParagraph">Once we've finished generating your video, we'll send you a link to download it.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 centerDescriptionButton">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Try it now</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="mainDescriptionHeading">Popular Templates</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!--card-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <video src="CreativeEngine/24052/COURTSMASH.mp4" alt="Card image cap" controls loop="true"></video>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-title">Card title</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Card Data bla bla bla.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Card-->
        <!--card-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <video src="CreativeEngine/24052/COURTSMASH.mp4" alt="Card image cap" controls loop="true"></video>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-title">Card title</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Card Data bla bla bla.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Card-->
        <!--card-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <video src="CreativeEngine/24052/COURTSMASH.mp4" alt="Card image cap" controls loop="true"></video>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-title">Card title</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Card Data bla bla bla.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Card-->
        <!--card-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <video src="CreativeEngine/24052/COURTSMASH.mp4" alt="Card image cap" controls loop="true"></video>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-title">Card title</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Card Data bla bla bla.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Card-->
        <!--card-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <video src="CreativeEngine/24052/COURTSMASH.mp4" alt="Card image cap" controls loop="true"></video>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-title">Card title</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Card Data bla bla bla.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Card-->
        <!--card-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <video src="CreativeEngine/24052/COURTSMASH.mp4" alt="Card image cap" controls loop="true"></video>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-title">Card title</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Card Data bla bla bla.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Card-->

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 centerDescriptionButton">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">See all templates</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `preload="auto"` to the `<video>` tag.